# Embed timestamp in object code at compile time with C++

Tags: c++, build, timestamp, versioning

I want to perform a `printf()` to display when the currently executing code was last compiled. Does C/C++ provide a macro that gives you that resolves to a timestamp during compilation?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Useful if you want to parse it https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129950/264822

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

Comment: @Inverse - You might modify your build process to recreate a file containing the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros on every compilation.

Comment: What I do is program the makefile to `touch` the file containing the macro before compilation in order to force its rebuild (ideally, the file containing the macros should be such that few, if any other files depend on it.

Answer (score 32):

> 16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]
>   1 The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>   `__LINE__` The line number of the current source line (a decimal constant).
>   `__FILE__` The presumed name of the source file (a character string literal).
>   `__DATE__` The date of translation of the source file (a character string literal of the form "Mmm dd yyyy", where the names of the months are the same as those generated by the asctime function, and the first character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10). If the date of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid date is supplied.
>   `__TIME__` The time of translation of the source file (a character string literal of the form "hh:mm:ss" as in the time generated by the asctime function). If the time of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid time is supplied.
>   `__STDC__` Whether `__STDC__` is predefined and if so, what its value is, are implementation-defined.
>   `__cplusplus` The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value 199711L when compiling a C++
>   translation unit.

You want `__TIME__` and possibly `__DATE__`.

Comment: @einpoklum: C has the same list of macros, and more, with some slight differences. For example, `__STDC__` is "The integer constant 1, intended to indicate a conforming implementation.", and `__cplusplus` is never defined. The full list in C11 is at §6.10.8.1.

Answer (score 8):

Use the macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using gcc preprocessor then you will find what you are looking for in the `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` macros

Quotes from GNU C pre-processor [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard%20Predefined%20Macros):

> __DATE__
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the date on which the preprocessor is being run. The string constant contains eleven characters and looks like "Feb 12 1996". If the day of the month is less than 10, it is padded with a space on the left.
>
> ...
>
> __TIME__
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes the time at which the preprocessor is being run. The string constant contains eight characters and looks like "23:59:01".

Comment: Just to point out: this has nothing to do with GCC. This is a standard thing. So you're right that the macros are as you say but it's not just for GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Use a script, or create an application, to generate a C++ source file containing the build date and time.  Add this file to the build setup.  The other parts of the program can reference the data in this file.

This technique is also useful for embedding a version number into the program.  The build process can control the version number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like compilers are expected to provide a `__TIMESTAMP__` macro, which ought to work for your purposes.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx): `__TIMESTAMP__` gives you the date and time of last edit (!) made to file (not the compilation time).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to send a message to DbgView:

```
    OutputDebugStringA(("ATTACHED VERSION: "+ string(__DATE__) + " " + string(__TIME__)).c_str());
```

Comment: Just a hint for better Performance:"ATTACHED VERSION: " `__DATE__` "  " `__TIME__` . works too.

Answer (score -1):

You can add below string to CMakeLists.txt

```
string(TIMESTAMP COMPILE_TIME %Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
```

and

you need to add below string to your "ProjectName.h.in" file

```
#define TIMESTAMP @COMPILE_TIME@
```

then when you compile your project, the below string will be written in your  "ProjectName.h"

```
#define TIMESTAMP 20230220-203532
```

Comment: OP never said anything about using CMake ... Also, you'd need more in your cmake than what you posted, and that would be the last time CMake ran, not when it was compiled.

Comment: emmm。May you write more detail about "you'd need more in your cmake than what you posted"?@ChrisMM