# Include last date of build in built code at build-time

Tags: typescript

Using for example the following code:

```
const buildDateTime = new Date(xy);
```

I would need to replace `xy` by the actual time my code was last built. The result would be to print:

> The software was built at {buildDateTime}.

It is supported [in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526933/embed-timestamp-in-object-code-at-compile-time-with-c), so I hope there is a way to achieve this in TypeScript as well.

Comment: I mean replace by fixed date. replace by date of compilation. Like the C++example I provided.

Comment: I tidied your question. At 14k, you should at least know how to properly format your code =p Please check the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that this isn't directly supported by TypeScript: there's no way to describe custom generated output in the way that you can with a language like C++.

Instead, I'd suggest generating a buildTime.txt file, and using that. E.g. in your package.json:

```js
"scripts": {
  "build": "date +%s > ./build/buildTime.txt && tsc"
}
```

and in your code, assuming this is Node.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./buildTime.txt', (buildTime) => {
  // Use your build time however you'd like
});
```